# Navigation drawer with custom adapter dont react correctly

Tags: java, android

I am trying to create Navigation Drawer who change fragments when its clicked. Its working fine with ArrayAdapter, but since i created my own CustomAdapter with web tut its only shows log and doesnt change fragment  and hide navDrawer. Here is my Adapter:

```
package com.gymcourses.qiteq.gymcourses;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    String[] result;
    Context context;
    int[] imageId;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater = null;
    private String mode;

    public CustomAdapter(Activity mainActivity, String[] prgmNameList, int[] prgmImages, String mode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        result = prgmNameList;
        this.mode = mode;
        context = mainActivity;
        imageId = prgmImages;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.
                getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        ;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return result.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    /*
    @Override
    public boolean areAllItemsEnabled(){
        return true;
    }
    */

    @Override
    public boolean isEnabled(int arg0){
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    public class Holder {
        TextView tv;
        ImageView img;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Holder holder = new Holder();
        View rowView;
        // mode "favorites" or "menu"
        switch (mode) {
            case "favorites":
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_listview_layout, null);
                break;
            case "menu":
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.navigation_drawer_custom_layout, null);
                break;
            default:
                rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.simple_listview_layout, null);
                Log.v("CustomAdapter.java: ", "doenst works");
        }
        holder.tv = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        holder.img = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        holder.tv.setText(result[position]);
        holder.img.setImageResource(imageId[position]);
        rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                String positionS = Integer.toString(position);
                Log.v("Item selected: ", positionS);
            }
        });
        return rowView;
    }
}
```

My layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:clickable="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_menu"
        android:padding="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:padding="0dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

And main activity:
Class:

```
package com.gymcourses.qiteq.gymcourses;

import android.app.Fragment;
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.ActivityNotFoundException;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
import android.net.NetworkInfo;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.zip.Inflater;

public class menu extends AppCompatActivity {
    private String[] mPlanetTitles;
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    public void editcontacts(View view) {
        Log.v("editcontacts", "clicked");
        Intent intent = new Intent(menu.this, EditContact.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    private class DrawerItemClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener{
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id){
            selectItem(position);
        }
    }

    private void selectItem(int position){
        Fragment fragment = new CategoryFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();

        args.putInt(CategoryFragment.ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER, position);
        fragment.setArguments(args);

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.drawerContent, fragment).commit();

        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_menu);


        mPlanetTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerLayoutList);
        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.drawer);
        int[] mImages = {R.drawable.ic_profile, R.drawable.ic_favorites, R.drawable.ic_notifications, R.drawable.ic_messages, R.drawable.ic_news, R.drawable.ic_discoveries, R.drawable.ic_artists, R.drawable.ic_users, R.drawable.ic_popular, R.drawable.ic_recommended, R.drawable.ic_genres, R.drawable.ic_settings, R.drawable.ic_settings};
        //mDrawerList.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(this, mPlanetTitles, mImages, "menu"));
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), R.layout.simple_listview_layout, mPlanetTitles));
        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new DrawerItemClickListener());

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        //Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar(getApplicationContext());

        mDrawerToggle = new android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout, R.string.drawer_open, R.string.drawer_close){
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view){
                super.onDrawerClosed(view);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView){
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
                getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                //invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
        //getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu);
        Log.v("Item selection", "start");
        selectItem(0);
        Log.v("Item selection", "false");
    }
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu){
        boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }


    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true;
        }
        /*
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.action_websearch:
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH);
                intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, getSupportActionBar().getTitle());
                if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null){
                    startActivity(intent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Sorry, there's no web browser avilable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                return true;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
        */
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    public static class CategoryFragment extends Fragment {
        public static final String ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER = "planet_number";

        public CategoryFragment() {
            // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
        }

                //FRAGMENT BUILDER//

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_fragment, container, false);
            /*int i = getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER);
            String planet = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.drawerLayoutList)[i];
            int imageId = getResources().getIdentifier(planet.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()), "drawable", getActivity().getPackageName());
            //((ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.image)).setImageResource(imageId);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.imageFragment);
            //getActivity().setTitle("Fragment");
            */
            String message = Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER));
            Log.v("Position: ", message);
            switch (getArguments().getInt(ARG_CATEGORY_NUMBER)){
                case 0:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_layout, container, false);

                    final String phoneNumber = "666555444";
                    final String emailContant = "example@example.com";
                    final String skypeContact = "skajpaj";

                    String nickname = "Qiteq";
                    String description = "My profile description";


                    TextView nicknamefield = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.nickname);
                    nicknamefield.setText(nickname);
                    TextView descriptionfield = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.description);
                    descriptionfield.setText(description);
                    ImageView avatarfield = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                    Drawable newAvatar = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.cat);
                    avatarfield.setImageDrawable(newAvatar);

                    if (phoneNumber!=null){
                        TextView contact1field = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contact1);
                        contact1field.setText(phoneNumber);
                        contact1field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL);
                                    callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" +phoneNumber));
                                    startActivity(callIntent);
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    if (emailContant!=null){
                        TextView contact2field = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.contact2);
                        contact2field.setText(emailContant);
                        contact2field.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
                            public void onClick(View v){
                                Intent sendEmail = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                sendEmail.setType("text/plain");
                                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] {emailContant});
                                /*
                                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
                                sendEmail.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "I'm email body.");
                                */

                                startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendEmail, "Send Email"));
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    break;
                case 1:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.favorites_layout, container, false);

                    String[] values = new String[]{"asdasd", "asdasdas", "asdasd", "asdasd"};
                    int[] images = {R.drawable.ic_menu, R.drawable.ic_menu, R.drawable.ic_menu, R.drawable.ic_menu};
                    ListView lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.favoritesListView);
                    lv.setAdapter(new CustomAdapter(getActivity(), values, images, "menu"));





                    break;
                case 2:
                    break;
                case 3:
                    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.news_layout, container, false);

                    break;
            }
            return rootView;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title){
        mTitle = title;
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig){
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }
}
```

and layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.gymcourses.qiteq.gymcourses.menu">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawerContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="240dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:background="#111"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

There is entire project:

> https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_yo7L-EKsdpWFVUSG91Z2dZbUE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I know this isn't what you asked for but maybe you have outdated information? If you haven't heard of it, look up NavigationView, it's used instead of a ListView inside the DrawerLayout and makes it a lot easier to setup a Material design standard Navigation Drawer. Here's an example tutorial http://www.android4devs.com/2015/06/navigation-view-material-design-support.html To implement the on click events of the drawer items, you just have to override one method. If you follow a tutorial on this NavigationView, you'd have a working drawer in less than 30minutes really...

Comment: For sure i will use it. I didnt know about other way to do NavDrawer. THank you man :)

Comment: No problem! Be sure to use up-to-date information and components as they get updated quite often in the mobile environment. Right now the design support library is quite famous cause it offers lots of material design UI capabilities to older devices as well. You'd need the dependency for it in order to use the NavigationView as well. But that should be in every tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the problematic line:

```
rowView.setOnClickListener...
```

DrawerItemClickListener.onItemClick can't be invoked because `rowView.setOnClickListener` intercepts the click

Also remove android:clickable="true" from "My layout"

Comment: I've removed that piece of code, and i added Log.v to onItemClick method.in DrawerItemClickListener, but still nothing happens, even Log.

EDIT:

I've removed line "android:clickable='true'" in NavDrawer layout and now it works fine. Thank you a lot :)